# Extension of a monoidal structure

Tags: category-theory, monoidal-categories

Let $\mathcal D$ be a dense subcategory of a category $\mathcal C$. Suppose that $\mathcal D$ admits a monoidal structure. Can the monoidal structure be extended from $\mathcal D$ to $\mathcal C$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a well known extension of $\mathcal D$'s monoidal structure $\otimes$ to its category of presheaves $\hat{\mathcal D}$ known as the Day convolution product $\hat\otimes$. It's uniquely specified by the requirements that the Yoneda embedding be strong monoidal and that $\hat\otimes$ be cocontinuous in each variable. Of course, the Yoneda embedding is the ur-example of a dense functor; we can try extend to your more general case from here. The density of $\mathcal D$ in $\mathcal C$ is equivalent to the full-faithfulness of the restricted Yoneda embedding $\mathcal C\to \hat{\mathcal D}$: in other words, pairs $\mathcal D\subset \mathcal C$ are equivalent to full subcategories of presheaf categories containing the representables.

Now it becomes clear that the Day convolution $\hat\otimes$ may not restrict to a monoidal product on $\mathcal C$, since there's no reason for a nearly arbitrary full subcategory to be $\hat\otimes$-closed. For instance, we could take $\mathcal D$ to be a discrete monoidal category, essentially just a monoid $D$. Then $\hat{\mathcal D}$ is the category of sets over $D$ with monoidal structure $(F\hat\otimes G)_d=\coprod_{d_1d_2=d}F_{d_1}\times F_{d_2}$. Then the full subcategory of sets over $D$ with at most one nonempty fiber is very far from $\hat\otimes$-closed.

It would be sufficient that $\mathcal C$ be coreflective in $\hat D$, but the only coreflective subcategory of a presheaf category containing the representables is the whole presheaf category, so this will never occur except in the simplest case. More interestingly, we can ask to *reflect* $\hat\otimes$ back into $\mathcal C$: if we have a reflection $L:\hat{ \mathcal D}\to \mathcal C$, then define $\otimes'$ on $\mathcal C$ as $L((-)\hat\otimes (-))$. This is how the tensor product of sheaves can be constructed. But sheaves are not just a reflective subcategory of presheaves, they're also closed under internal homs, and you will not be able to prove that $\otimes'$ is associative without requiring that $\mathcal C$ be closed under internal homs in $\hat D$. (Internal homs for the Day product are defined by cocontinuity, just as for $\hat\otimes$ itself.) Day himself published a theorem characterizing reflective subcategories of monoidal closed categories closed under internal homs [here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/0022404972900217/1-s2.0-0022404972900217-main.pdf?_tid=2fef5052-004b-11e7-934e-00000aab0f6b&acdnat=1488571038_c88b12d7cab4363b0800503deb9763ea).

Unfortunately I know no general techniques by which to check his conditions for a non-Cartesian monoidal structure. However, in case $\mathcal D$ is Cartesian, $\hat{\mathcal D}$ is as well, and then we can reflect $\hat\otimes=\times$ into $\mathcal C$ if and only if the reflection $L$ preserves finite products, which brings us back again to the world of sheaves. In this case, of course, we're not impressed: we've just reflected the Cartesian product into a reflective subcategory, which we knew was closed under limits anyway! However, this argument does show that we'll be able to reflect $\hat\otimes$ into $\mathcal C$ only if $\mathcal C$ is also closed, with the same homs as in  $\hat{\mathcal D}$, which was certainly not obvious to begin with; furthermore, one can use the argument on non-Cartesian monoidal products derived from the Cartesian one, such as, of course, the tensor product of abelian group objects.

In short, the answer is: not in general, but there's a natural condition you can check in particular cases.

Comment: Thank you, very nice. However, I think that it is too much to demand transf

Comment: &%!!! I think it is (at least in the case I am interested in) too much to demand that $\mathcal C$ is closed under internal homs of $\hat{\mathcal D}$. I remember reading somewhere that to transfer a monoidal structure to a reflective subcategory, it suffices that the reflection preserves something (reflexive (co)equalizers?). But I cannot find it now, maybe I am wrong.

Comment: Well, of course every reflection will preserve any colimit you care to name, so that won't do it. The theorem of Day I cite is the general condition for transfer of monoidal structure. Maybe there's another relevant special case you're half-remembering, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

You can if you have a bit more information than just the monoidal structure. This is Proposition 9 from "Categorical and combinatorial aspects of descent theory ", by Street, where he attributes this result to Day. With your notation the result is the following:

Suppose $J : \mathcal D \to \mathcal C$ is a dense functor from a small monoidal category $\mathcal D$ into a complete and cocomplete category $\mathcal C$. The formula
$$
c_1 \otimes c_2 := \int^{d_1,d_2} (\mathcal C(Jd_1,c_1) \times \mathcal C(c_2,Jd_2)) \cdot J(d_1\otimes d_2)
$$
defines a (left and right) closed monoidal structure on X with J strong monoidal if and
only if there exist functors $H$ and $H′ : \mathcal D^{op} \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$ and isomorphisms 
$$\mathcal C(Jd_1, H(d_2,c)) \cong \mathcal C(J(d_1 \otimes d_2),c) \cong \mathcal C(Jd_2,H'(d_1,c))  
$$
natural in objects $d_1$ and $d_2$ of $\mathcal D$ and $c$ of $\mathcal C$.

This result is reformulated as follows in "Joint et tranches pour les $\infty$-catégories strictes" by Ara and Maltsiniotis (in French, Theorem 6.9):

Let $\mathcal C$ be a complete and cocomplete category, and $\mathcal D$ be a full subcategory of $\mathcal C$ equipped with a monodical structure.  Suppose there exists a small full subcategory of $\mathcal D$ dense in $\mathcal C$, and functors 
$H$ and $H′ : \mathcal D^{op} \times \mathcal C \to \mathcal C$, together with  bijections $$\mathcal C(Jd_1, H(d_2,c)) \cong \mathcal C(J(d_1 \otimes d_2),c) \cong \mathcal C(Jd_2,H'(d_1,c))  
$$
natural in objects $d_1$ and $d_2$ of $\mathcal D$ and $c$ of $\mathcal C$.

Then there exists a unique monodical structure on $\mathcal C$ (up to unique monodical isomorphism) given by a product which commutes to small colimits in each variable, and for which the inclusion functor $\mathcal D \to \mathcal C$ extends into a monoidal functor. Moreover, this monodical structure is biclosed.

Still in this last article, the authors then extend this result to construct products that only commute to small *connected* colimits (Corollary 6.14). However that only works if the unit of the monoidal product on $\mathcal D$ is an initial object of $\mathcal C$. If you are interested I can translate the result to English but it is a pretty niche case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think there is a typo in the coend formula, it should be $\mathcal C(Jd_1,c_1)\times\mathcal C(Jd_2,c_2)$, right?